# Get position of character with conditions

Tags: javascript

I got a string with some aliases (for instance "MM").
I initiate the aliases with an '@' character. The String could be look like "This message goes to @GR,MM. Glad to see you!". Maybe also "@GR This sentece is not very valide, but should also work,MM"

My function has to remove the given alias out of the string. Maybe the best and only way is to check left and right beside the alias itself ("@" or ",").
Someone an Idea how to check left and right beside the alias to decide either to remove or not?

underscore.js and underscore.string are o.k

Example:

function removeAlias(alias, description) return description

If description includes alias, remove and return without it

Cases:

"@ME, MH In this string, remove MH" 
Result: @ME In this string, remove MH"

"@MH In this string, remove MH"
Result: In this string, remove MH

"@GR In this string, remove ,MH"
Result: "@GR In this string, remove"

Comment: So `@GR This sentece is not very valide, but should also work,MM` should become `This sentece is not very valide, but should also work`?

Comment: Thank you for reply. No it's correct that also the alias could be at the end of the line.

Comment: Hi @Patrik Your question is not clear. Please add some examples, cases and desired results.

Comment: still your conditions are not clear...

Comment: Are you sure that's the expected result in the second case?

Comment: I think you may need to write a computer program to do this.

Answer (score 0):

According to the cases you posted, I think this might be what you want

```
function removeAlias(alias, description) {
    return description.replace(new RegExp('[@,]*' + alias + ' *'), '');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Look for [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) and use String.replace:

```
function removeAlias(alias, text) {

  // look for a 'word boundary' (\b)
  // followed by zero or more '@' caracters (@*)
  // followed by the given alias
  // followed by another 'word boundary'
  var regex = new RegExp("\b@*"+alias+"\b");
  // replace by empty string
  var result = text.replace(regex, "");
  return result;
}
```

Maybe you need to adjust the actual regex according to your actual requirements.